# Redis: Is PUBLISH asynchronous?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

If I `PUBLISH` a message on Redis that has one subscriber but that subscriber takes 1 second to receive the message will is block the `PUBLISH` for one second or do they act independently?

If they act independently how many `PUBLISH` commands will be queued before bad stuff starts happening?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`PUBLISH` is synchronous - you also may find sources of this command in pubsub.c function `publishCommand` and `pubsubPublishMessage`. Redis is single threaded application. So, strictly, all his commands is synchronous.

Comment: I don't think it is true. I'm quite sure that Redis is using nonblocking IO and enqueues publications to clients, rather than blocking on each slow consumer.

Comment: According to redis documentation https://redis.io/topics/pubsub, "published messages are characterized into channels, without knowledge of what (if any) subscribers there may be". I really doubt it waits for the subcriber to respond. Who shoud it wait for, every subscriber? At least one? If one of them hangs, the entire instance is down? I don't think so.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski the publish is synchronous. It`s iterate throw all list of subscribers and send them event one by one. Yes, the network layer is nonblocking IO but this is not about the original question. If you have 1000 memebers in channel it would be inplace synchronous iteration for 1000 clients.

Answer (score -1):

Dont think the answer or comments are very clear.
From an outside callers perspective using a redis client, if I had a single thread/process running that back to back subscribed to a channel and then immediately wrote to that same channel and tested if it got the message echo'd back to it.  Is there a chance of a race condition b/c the subscription is not fully registered or complete by time the client responses and starts writing first message... ??

Perhaps core redis server supports both and it depends on the client being used, but not sure....